# Find the Highest Common Factor of: $acx^3+(bc+ad)x^2+(bd+ac)x+bc$ $\\$ and $\\$ $2acx^3+(2bc-ad)x^2-(3ac+bd)x-3bc$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the Highest Common Factor of:

$acx^3+(bc+ad)x^2+(bd+ac)x+bc$ $\\$ and $\\$ $2acx^3+(2bc-ad)x^2-(3ac+bd)x-3bc$

Solution:

$acx^3+(bc+ad)x^2+(bd+ac)x+bc = acx^3+bcx^2+adx^2+bdx+acx+bc$

$2acx^3+(2bc-ad)x^2-(3ac+bd)x-3bc=2acx^3+2bcx^2-adx^2-3acx-bdx-3bc$

$$
\begin{array}{c | c | c}
acx^3+bcx^2+adx^2+bdx+acx+bc & & 2acx^3+2bcx^2-adx^2-3acx-bdx-3bc \\
& - & 2acx^3+2bcx^2+2adx^2+2acx+2bdx+2bc \\
\hline
& & -3adx^2-5acx-3bdx-5bc
\end{array}  
$$

$\Rightarrow -3adx^2-5acx-3bdx-5bc \\ \Rightarrow-3dx(ax+b)-5c(ax+b) \\ \Rightarrow (ax+b)(-3dx-5c)$

Here's the problem. The Highest Common Factor is either $(ax+b)$ or $(-3dx-5c)$. I can't tell which, and I know I could just take each one and do long division, but I don't want to do that. So is there a way just by *looking* to tell which one is the Highest Common Factor? Thank you.

Comment: Either factor is easy to try. If you were to guess, then by analogy with the rational root theorem you would expect a factor $mx+n$ to observe $n \mid bc$ and $m \mid ac$ which leaves only one of the two to consider.

Comment: You can continue with polynomial division if you want a mechanical method. There is nothing so far to suggest that the highest common factor cannot include both of the factors you have found, or indeed neither. On the other hand reducing modulo 3 might get you somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

$(ax+b)(−3dx−5c) = 0$

This thing is just $f(x) -2g(x) =0$ , so possible solutions are either common roots of $f$ and $g$ or a value of $x$ such that $f(x) = 2g(x)$. You've obtained two factors $x = \frac{-b}{a} $ and $x = \frac{-5c}{3d}$, Upon substitution you would notice that $\frac{-b}{a}$ is a root and $\frac{-5c}{3d}$ isn't. Hence $ax+b$ is highest and only factor